# Did US propaganda change eating habits in Turkey post WW2?

Tags: united-states, propaganda

There is a story going on here in Turkey about propaganda efforts by the US to change eating habits of the population to sell surplus US corn and corn products to Turkey. Is it possible to find legal documents to corroborate these stories?

It is said that the US commissioned a folk song that told people not to eat olive oil. They made this song very popular and people started to eat more margerine made with the US corn. The folk song in question is still popular and can be heard in r[adios even today](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wyvkIvaFU4I). 
Is there a way to find documentation that the US public relations departments indeed was able to create a successful folk song in Turkish. Sounds a little outrageous to me.

Comment: This fails a basic plausibility test; the US "made this song popular", but couldn't make corn popular? Exactly how does one force people to like a song?  It is entirely possible that they made a song that became popular, but if they could control the popularity of the song, they could have controlled the popularity of the margarine, and skipped the song. The USA doesn't have a magical mind control machine.  (and if we did, it wouldn't be deployed over margarine.)

Comment: Seems answerable with relation to US margarine monopolist association or US Trade department documentation. Unlikely to have been investigated specifically though.

Comment: How you distinguish "propaganda to sell a product" from advertisements and commercials? Making a song (obviously not a folk song) for commercials doesn't sound like anything unique or malicious.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace `Exactly how does one force people to like a song` The same way they make movies popular; they pay to put them in mass media as often as possible. In this case it is even easier, because the public does not need to pay anything to receive the pretended product (the song) and the actual message. You can google about the "payola" practice.

Comment: @Greg in some countries (do not know the specifics about Turkey), commercial (paid for) messages must be publicly acknowledged as that (in the USA, the Payola case is also a good example). So comissioning a Turkish song about the margerine benefits and buying air time for it without disclosing that it was part of a commercial campaign could have been illegal. That said, the OP could make a better explanation of the actual impact, legality/ilegality in Turkey, sources for the claim, etc.

Comment: @SJuan76 I guess it would benefit the question if OP would elaborate on the details. Only the language of OP and the question asking for legal documents suggest the something illegal / unethical happened, but nothing specific point to illegal practices. Also, the language is very vague/using wrong terms: US PR deparments? folk song? Without specifics it can be just a patriotic (nationalistic) propaganda as well.